# Get all permutations of values - into pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permutation

I have X amount of values being passed into a table via CSV - so I take 99315,99316,99223 and split them out into a single column temp table - each value in the CSV into a single row.

What I need to be able to do is to get every permutation of values in pairs - 
so - something like:

```
Col1     Col2
99315    99316
99315    99223
99316    99315
99316    99223
99223    99315
99223    99316
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1 col2
from mytable t1
cross join mytable t2
```

if you want to exclude like values add

```
where t1.col1 <> t2.col1
```

Comment: Beat my cross-join answer by 30 seconds.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to write this query is to just do

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1 col2
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

and then you can add filters with a WHERE as well